# css3 flex : how a cell can take the exact place?

Tags: css

Here is my snippet:

```css
#container {
 display: flex;
}
#red {
  background-color:red;
}
#green {
  background-color:green;

  width:100%;
 
}
#blue {
  background-color:blue;
width:100px;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="red">Hello world hello world hello world</div>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>    
</div>
```

**My problem is that red part wraps in 2 lines**.

I tried with **flex-grow:1**

But then red part takes too much space !

**My goal is to have the red part take as much space as necessary wuth no line breaking and no extra space** : content of the red part will be modified with JS later.

(I am not sure flex is the good option, maybe some other display will help)

red is flexible, green should take as much space as possible, blue is fixed 100px

Answer (score -1):

Replace your styles with below styles.

```
#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: red is flexible, green should take as much space as possible, blue is fixed 100px

Answer (score -1):

You should provide the width to the #red.

```
#red {
  background-color:red;
  width:80%
}
#green {
  background-color:green;
    width:20%
}
```

http://jsbin.com/yuhitezohi/2/

Comment: red is flexible, green should take as much space as possible, blue is fixed 100px